# A single value used in different files in angular.How to write it?

Tags: angular

I am using angular for front end.

In this, a single value like `role id` which is used in different .ts file in Angular.

How to efficiently write this?

Please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You can put that value in services and can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It many ways to get one value in multiple components.

1. Pass in the `Services` and get the value like this

   ```
   roleId: any;
   issendId(roleId) {
       this.roleId= roleId;
   }
   isreciveId() {
       return this.roleId;
   }
   ```
2. Other way use of `viewChild()`

   ```
   @ViewChild(SenderComponent) private sendId: SenderComponent;
   ngOnInit(){
       sendId.roleId;
   }
   ```

   SenderComponent

   `roleId: any = 2 ;`